# How to get 3 items from the pivot table via Eloquent (Laravel)?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

A bit of business logic: 1 company may have many users with different roles. 1 user may have only 1 role in company.

In the database I have a pivot table `company_user_roles`. There're 3 fields: `company_id, user_id, role_id`. Then I have a `User` model and `belongsToMany` relation for getting user's companies:

```
public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
         'App\Company', 
         'company_user_roles', 
         'user_id', 
         'company_id'
        );
    }
```

`$user->companies` returns a collection of companies. But there's no user's role in each company. I have only this for each company (and it seems to be expected):

```
#attributes: array:4 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "name" => "Company name"
        "created_at" => "2018-07-08 15:45:40"
        "updated_at" => "2018-07-08 15:45:42"
]
```

But I don't understand how to get a role of the user for each company. I want to get something like this:

```
#attributes: array:4 [▼
            "id" => 1
            "name" => "Company name"
            "role" => [
              "id": 1,
              "name": "owner"
            ]
            "created_at" => "2018-07-08 15:45:40"
            "updated_at" => "2018-07-08 15:45:42"
    ]
```

Or something like this, but without extra queries to the database. How to implement this logic in this case?

Answer (score 1):

There is one solution to add `belongsTo` relation in your `pivot` model `CompanyUserRole` 
but then you can't load that `belongsTo` relation from your pivot using eager loading. 
The second solution is to use `hasMany` relationship, when you have more than 2 foreign key in pivot table.

**User Model**

```
public function roleUserCompanies(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\CompanyUserRole'); 
}
```

**Company Model**

```
public function roleCompanyUsers(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\CompanyUserRole'); 
}
```

**CompanyUserRole Model**

```
class CompanyUserRole extends Model {
    protected $table = 'company_user_roles';

    public function company(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
    }

    public function user(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }


    public function role(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }
}
```

**Fetch data**

```
$user = User::with('roleUserCompanies', 'roleUserCompanies.company', 'roleUserCompanies.role')->find(1);

foreach($user->roleUserCompanies as $roleUserCompany){
    dd($roleUserCompany->company);
    dd($roleUserCompany->role);
}
```

Hope this may help you

Comment: Worked a treat that workout around, thanks a lot!